# Can I bring back electronic components from Taiwan?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, france, singapore, taiwan

I'm currently in Taiwan and the CPU/GPU are cheaper here than in France. Is there any law or regulation preventing me to buy some for me and my friend and to come back to France with them (I may also go to Singapore before France)?

Edit:
The value of each item will be at least 250€.

Comment: To be considered “personal baggage” .. by [definition](https://franceintheus.org/IMG/pdf/trouble_free_travel_with_french_customs-2.pdf) “ the nature or the amount of the goods in the baggage must not imply commercial purposes”. So potentially a judgement call by the customs official.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unless these products are under Taiwanese export restrictions, there's no issue on that side. In France, if you are over 15 landing in France from outside the EU, your duty-free allowance is 430€. Anything above that has to be declared (whether you do or not... it's up to you).

[Source](https://www.service-public.fr/particuliers/vosdroits/F50#:%7E:text=Vous%20devez%20d%C3%A9clarer%20verbalement%20aux,des%20marchandises%20de%20l%27a%C3%A9roport.).

If you go first to Singapore, you run into the problem of having to pass through Customs (Singapore Customs decide, supposedly on a case by case, whether you have to scan your bags. Last time I went there, a whole bunch of Indians had to, and I whizzed by without being asked anything...). In which case you could explain to the officers that this will be re-exported to France. You might have to leave it with them, depending on their mood, the quantity, etc.

But more probably, you'll be just fine.

Comment: It depends. Go by car, train or other means it;s 300 euro. Arrive by plane or ferry its 430 euro (not sure why a ferry is not a boat). Under 15? 150 euro. Also, the government of France publishes this information in English https://www.douane.gouv.fr/fiche/volume-and-value-based-customs-and-tax-allowances (scroll to the `Value-based allowances`  header).

Comment: Considering the OP is coming back from Taiwan, or Singapore, yeah, car or train is out...

Comment: Read OPs post carefully.

Comment: Duh. Why do you think my answer was accepted.

Answer (score 6):

> Is there any law or regulation preventing me to buy some for me and my friend

No.

However, depending on the value of the electronics you will have to declare them at customs and pay duty upon arrival in France.

Comment: Hilmar, can you please improve this answer by editing in the value they can bring home before they have to declare?